# Current culture of my application is set to Polish but i need to convert my date to English in order to perform database operations

Tags: c#

currently date is coming in this format: "12-Kwi-2019"

I need to convert this to : "12-Apr-2019"

what i have tried until now

```
var monthNames = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++)
   {
     monthNames[i] = monthNames[i].TrimEnd('.');
   }
currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = monthNames;
monthNames = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames;
for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++)
   {
     monthNames[i] = monthNames[i].TrimEnd('.');
   }
currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = monthNames;
 var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("12-Kwi-2019", "dd-MMM-yyyy", currentCulture);
```

Comment: what is the value of `currentCulture` ?

Comment: `but i need to convert my date to English in order to perform database operations` No. You need to pass the date to the database **as a date**. Please show us your DB code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Polish culture:

```
var polishCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("12-Kwi-2019", "dd-MMM-yyyy", polishCulture);
var s = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```